# Реализация зашифрованной передачи данных с сервера клиенту

Tags: php, javascript, алгоритм, шифрование

Требуется передать данные из `PHP` в `Javascript` в таком виде, чтобы невооруженный глаз не заметил бы о чем идет речь. А затем расшифровать их.
По такому типу:

```
<?php
$data = 'some data string';
function my_encode_function($string){
...
}
?>
<script>
    var encoded_data = '<?php echo my_encode_function($data); ?>';
    var decoded_data = my_decode_function(encoded_data);

    function my_decode_function($string){
    ...
    }
</script>
```

Не требуется какой-то несокрушимый метод шифровки. Нужно только скрыть данные от невооруженного глаза (различные провайдеры и фильтры, которые суют нос не в свое дело). Так что основное требование - экономия во времени выполнения и в написании кода (лучше всего - встроенные функции php и js).

Comment: Base64 в чистом виде или с измененным словарем.

Comment: ну если только "невооруженный глаз" нужен, то можно простой `xor` использовать. Только взломать его легко

Comment: Зашифруйте в base64 функцией `base64_encode()` в PHP и расшифруйте JQuery плагином https://plugins.jquery.com/base64/ в JS

Comment: @mix есть же всякие atob() и btoa()...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Проблема в том, что `atob()` (`js` функция расшифровывания base64), на сколько я понял, поддерживается не всеми браузерами. А подключения дополнительной библиотеки для такой чепухи, хотелось бы избежать.

Comment: @s976 Тогда можно ее просто переписать с C.

Comment: @s976 Можно также написать php обработчик, который будет получать строку и возвращать её зашифровку или расшифровку и ajax'ом на стороне js делать запрос.

Comment: @mix ни SHA1, ни MD5 не являются алгоритмами шифрования.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Ну да, можно и написать эту функцию. Есть уже даже [готовые решения для JS](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/qAGHT/), но уж может тогда я сделаю что-то и попроще, мне достаточно просто charCode для каждого символа увеличить или уменьшить на единицу...

Comment: @mix base64 обычно невооруженным взглядом по знакам равно на конце видно, полсекунды уходит что бы понять что это

Comment: @Mike допустим, ты понял, что это html код, твои действия?

Comment: @mix причем тут html. если мне станет интересно что со знаками равно на конце скрыто то применю base64_decode, заготовки обычно под рукой

Comment: @Mike допустим, ты удовлетворил свое любопытство, что дальше будешь делать?

Comment: @mix Я, скорее всего ничего. но если данные не хотят посылать открытым видом то видимо хоть на сколько то их скрыть. Я просто уже видел рутовые пароли в base64 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать модифицированную base85 кодировку. По сравнению с стандартом сделаны следующие изменения: диапазон символов сдвинут на 9 вправо, `\` кодируется как `!`, первым символом в строке идет число "лишних" символов. Данные изменения позволили значительно упростить алгоритм и исключить кавычки из кодированной строки, что облегчает печать строки в JS код.

PHP кодирование:

```
function base85X_encode($t) {
  $l=strlen($t); $o=4-($l%4); $l+=$o; $t.="zzzz";
  for($i=0;$i < $l;$i+=4):
    $n=unpack("N",substr($t,$i,4))[1];
    for($j=0;$j<5;$j++):
      $o.=(chr($n%85+42));
      $n=(int)($n/85);
    endfor;
  endfor;
  return str_replace('\\','!',$o);
}
```

JS декодер:

```
function base85X_decode(t) {
  t=t.replace(/!/g,'\\');
  var l=t.length,o="",pad="00000000";
  for(var i=1;i<l;i+=5) {
    for(var j=0,n=0,m=1;j<5;j++) { n+=(t.charCodeAt(i+j)-42)*m; m*=85; }
    var s=n.toString(16);
    s=pad.substring(0,8-s.length)+s;
    o+=s.replace(/(..)/g,"%$1");
  }
  return decodeURIComponent(o.substring(0,o.length-t[0]*3));
}
```

Русские символы в передаваемой строке *должны* быть в UTF-8 в связи с особенностями работы с такими символами в JS.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает отлично. Это при том, что кодировка base64 и раскодировка через atob() работала корректно только для англ. языка.

Comment: @s976 В jQuery плагине для base64, который выше предлагали, вопрос с UTF решен, кстати. Но громоздко очень

Comment: @s976 Я поправил в ответе JS декодер, возьмите эту версию. В предыдущей были проблемы на некоторых комбинациях символов.

Comment: Ок. Спасибо. На самом деле, я бы хотел просто сместить код символа. (это будет работать быстрее, и мне этого вполне достаточно) Но стандартный подход, освещенный в руководствах не подходит для UTF-8. Попробую воспользоваться Вашим кодом, чтобы понять как это делать.

Comment: @s976 В JS просто символы которые должны класться в строку как двухбайтные в принципе нельзя побайтно обработать и в эту строку положить. Поэтому я и сделал хак с записью всех декодированных символов в hex виде, добавлением символа % и декодировке decodeURIcomponent. Но надо иметь ввиду, что если при сдвиге образуются недопустимые в UTF комбинации то кодированная строка будет неправильно воспринята JS. Поэтому кодирование 7-ми битными символами предпочтительно