# Как передать значение из PHP в JS без вывода в html и ajax?

Tags: php

Есть достаточно тяжелый серверный скрипт, который подключается с помощью `require` на страницу index.php. Одно из значений выводить прямо в html нельзя, так как большая угроза curl парсинга. Повторный запрос, но уже через ajax так же невозможен по понятным причинам (время выполнения). Какие еще есть способы передать значение? Спасибо.

Comment: Любое значение переданное по сети может быть перехвачено, так что  защищаться от парсинга смысла нет. Можете "значение" конечно в виде картинки отдать

Comment: Этот уже философия. Ресурсы затраченные на взлом всегда должны быть дороже самого продукта. Под защитой я понимаю ситуацию, когда проще купить, а не воровать. Но это не касается темы. `curl` не исполняет js и в моем случае этого достаточно.

Comment: Т.е. вы боитесь именно curl ... Лично я для парсингда предпочитаю использовать сам web-браузер и прасить плагином к нему, так даже проще получается, из готового dom достать значения элементарно. А в вашем случае вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. высылайте данные в виде <script> в теле которого они будут зашифрованы и расшифровываться на клиенте js. Правда увидев такое при желании это парсить я бы просто переписал код расшифровщика со страницы на нужном языке

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472363/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83/472509#472509

Comment: http://www.seleniumhq.org/ и никаких плагинов к браузеру писать не надо. Минимум усилий, максимум возможностей. Если нужна защита от "простого подсматривания", то можно отдавать клиенту на странице зашифрованное значение, а клиент потом отправляет это значение на сервер и получает расшифровку. При шифровке/расшифровке можно использовать, например, id сессии. Тогда, если значение перехватят, без сессии расшифровать его не смогут. Но от того же selenium'а не поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Велосипед на костылях**:

Выполнив «тяжёлый» скрипт помещайте «секретное» значение в кэш в памяти – memcached / redis / APC – может, используется уже какой-то? Создавайте случайный ключ и значением ему ставьте это «секретное». И срок жизни минут 5 – по обстоятельствам.

В html отдавайте ключ, в каком-нибудь хитром виде, требующем JS манипуляций. И пусть ajax-запрос через минимальный лёгчайший скрипт вытаскивает из кэша само секретное значение.

**Самокат**:

Значение отдавайте в виде маленького JS скрипта, который должен выполниться для получения самого значения. Можно придумать несколько нехитрых алгоритмов, один из которых будет случайно выбираться каждый раз, чтобы curl'исты не сразу сделали на своей стороне расшифровщик.

Напр. значение-строку переворачивать и сдвигать на N. Если там число – сдвигать биты на M. Значения N и M варьировать и передавать вместе с кодом.