# Шифровка и расшифровка на php

Tags: php

Есть код товара: `544049568640` возможно ли это шифровать например как то так: `ZUePM2pD7zChI1` потом обратно расшифровать в `544049568640`

- `544049568640` такой вид нужно для запроса
- `ZUePM2pD7zChI1` а этот вид нужно для пользователя

еще есть вариант что пользователь может поискать товары в таком виде: `544049568640` тогда такую не надо шифровать, может у кого нибудь было похожие ситуации?

Comment: Ничего, в общем-то, не понятно. 544049568640 -> ZUePM2pD7zChI1 скорее никак не зашифровать, можно только закодировать. Но все равно не вижу смысла.

Comment: Возьмите какой нибудь base64. Или например модифицированный base85 я тут делал для похожих случаев https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472363/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83/472509#472509

Comment: в php есть по крайней мере 2 вида хеширования md5 и sha1.  Но это необратимое шифрование

Comment: Можно хранить в БД два ID: внутренний, для запроса, и публичный, для пользователей. Правда, это к шифрованию отношения не имеет

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick Никакое хэширование не является шифрованием, потому что оно необратимо.

Comment: Если кодирование кажется ненадежным перед ним можно применить любой шифр вроде DES, AES и т.п.

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать Base64 или openssl_encrypt Это если принципиально шифрование. Если просто нужны буквы, я бы простое кодирование сделал.

Comment: Судя по примеру, нужно 12-значное число кодировать в 14-символьный код? не вижу великой проблемы нарисовать собственную функцию, которая это сделает - отображение 12 символов по основанию 10 в 14 символов по основанию 62... с другой стороны, это всё явно хранится в БД - так что в разы проще при вводе записи с 12-значным кодом товара в дополнительном поле формировать рандомный 14-символьный код (проверив на всякий случай на дублирование), и использовать именно его.

Comment: Не надо чтобы прямо как на примере @Mike спасибо за вариант можно сделать как то так `echo base64_encode('544049568640');
echo base64_decode('NTQ0MDQ5NTY4NjQw');` но тут отпадает последний вариант в `base64_decode` может попасть внутренний код т.е 544049568640 и не понятно как тут быть

Comment: @newProgrammer допишите к строке перед кодированием какой нибудь признак и после декодирования если его нет, значит декодирование считать не верным и использовать изначальный вариант. или уже после кодирования в начало строки добавьте например букву z по наличию которой вы сразу поймете что это именно кодированная строка (если конечно в обычном коде товара не может быть z).

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать [mcrypt_decrypt](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) и [mcrypt_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mcrypt-cbc.php)

Comment: Для использования в URL все таки base64 думаю предпочтительнее, меньше символов которые в URL должны быть закодированы. Особенно если `+` и `/` на что то заменить. В 85 кодировке слишком много спец-символов, она для печати в текст JS подходит, экранировать ничего не надо, а для URL некрасиво смотреться будет

Comment: [вот](https://github.com/pictaile/test_mycrt/blob/master/index.php) с помощью Mcrypt  реализация

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick mcrypt функции устаревшие но вариант не плохой использовать можно спасибо, сделайте код как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.mcrypt.php) криптографические расширения для php.

функции дешифрования и шифрования
[mcrypt_decrypt()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)
[mcrypt_encrypt()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)

Код, который будет шифровать/дешифровать будет выглядеть так:

```
<?php
$string = '544049568640'; 
$iv = '55555555'; 
$passphrase = '8chrsLng'; 

$encryptedString = encryptString($string, $passphrase, $iv); 

$decryptedString = decryptString($encryptedString, $passphrase, $iv); 

function encryptString($unencryptedText, $passphrase, $iv) { 
  $enc = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $passphrase, $unencryptedText, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); 
  return base64_encode($enc); 
} 

function decryptString($unencryptedText, $passphrase, $iv) {
  $enc = base64_decode($unencryptedText);
  $enc = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $passphrase, $enc, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); 
  return  rtrim($enc, "\0");
} 

var_dump($encryptedString);
var_dump($decryptedString);
```

> Это расширение объявлено устаревшим в PHP 7.1.0 и перемещено в PECL в PHP 7.2.0.